# Bootstrap glyphicon/nav bar showing popup window

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a few things from bootstrap in my template, like glyphicon's and a navbar. Which is on my "forum.php". Now when I want to delete a topic, I want a javascript popup to show up which is working just fine. But through that popup I can see bootstraps navbar and glyphicon. How do I fix this?

forum.php

```
    <table class="overview">
       <tr class="row1">
         <td class="col1">
            <button>
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
               </span>
            </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </table>

        <button onclick="showDiv()">Delete category</button>
```

css.css

```
#popup_container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
opacity:.99;
top:0;
left:0;
display: none;
position:fixed;
background-color:#313131;
overflow:auto
}

#prompt-delete {
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:17%;
margin-left:-202px;
}
```

popup.php

```
<div id="popup_container">
   <div id="prompt-delete">
      <h2> my popup</h2>
      <button onclick="closeDiv()">Close</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript.js

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('popup_container').style.display = "block";
}

function closeDiv() {
   document.getElementById("popup_container").style.display = "none";
}
```

When popup is showing, through that div, on the background I see the glypicon of bootstrap without being faded into the background. It shows without opacity.
The rest of the page is faded with the opacity defined in the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change The `z-index` of your pop-up to 1.

Comment: Thanks, z-index works. For people who like to know what z-index does. It defines what (in this case) div shows first. This can also be done for images, text etc.